# index for `where wakeup_time < sysdate`

Tags: oracle, date, indexing

For most records this field is null.  I need to wake up only some records.

The table is very big and I want to know which records to wake up.  I don't want database to seek every row.   Could you show me your idea?

Answer (score 2):

Create an ordinary index on just (`WAKEUP_TIME`). Only the rows where `WAKEUP_TIME` is not null will be stored in the index. When `WAKEUP_TIME` is updated to `NULL`, the entry will be removed from the index, so the index will be the most efficient way of finding all the rows that match your predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create an index on wakeup_time? Also, you may fill it with a far away date by default, like 3000-01-01.

Comment: Agree with the index on wakeup_time. Disagree with the 'far away' default as Oracle doesn't index null values so an index on a column with lots of nulls will be small whereas an index on a column with lots of default values will be large.